# How to list the amount of posts per hour of each day in MYSQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, modeling

Currently I made a script that gets the amount of all posts by time of day.

[initial solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpO2x.png)

How to make a script that shows the amount of posts per hour of each day?

01-01-2022 00:00:00 = 30
01-01-2022 01:00:00 = 23
01-01-2022 02:00:00 = 15
01-01-2022 03:00:00 = 15
01-01-2022 04:00:00 = 9
01-01-2022 05:00:00 = 11
[...]
02-01-2022 00:00:00 = 21
02-01-2022 01:00:00 = 11
02-01-2022 02:00:00 = 13
[...]
03-02-2022 00:00:00 = 21
03-02-2022 01:00:00 = 11
03-02-2022 02:00:00 = 13

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq6s3.png)

DATABASE SQL ALCHEMY

class Tweet(db.Model):
id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True) 
idUser = db.Column(db.String(50)) 
username = db.Column(db.String(100)) 
tweet = db.Column(db.String(999)) 
createdAt = db.Column(db.DateTime) 
lang = db.Column(db.String(100)) 
tag = db.Column(db.String(150)) 
 
def **init**(self, idUser, username, tweet, createdAt, lang, tag): 
self.idUser = idUser 
self.username = username 
self.tweet = tweet 
self.createdAt = createdAt 
self.lang = lang 
self.tag = tag

Comment: how to do with database query without programming?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it depends on how you are registering posts and what´s the final goal for the result.
But may be you would try doing a select for your desired date interval using COUNT over the post_id field (if you have it) and then use GROUP BY user.

Comment: you say make a query to get all createdat and then run a for in python to get the posts by hour of that given day?or if you put it by interval it will come by the hour

the ultimate goal is then to put it in a graph that can show how many posts were made at a given time of day